# How prove an equality

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

We have $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+10}$ and we need to show: $\int_{-10}^{10} f(x) \, dx = 2\int_0^{10} f(x) \, dx$

First method I find the primitive for this function and after I put the value and I obtain this equality.But how we can easily prove this equality?

Comment: [This](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fproofwiki.org%2Fwiki%2FDefinite_Integral_of_Even_Function&ei=ziYdVZW8L8Hx8gXB9IGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNHoPcYQvNMLWNA6zou5iwEL2BrzYg) and [this.](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FEven_and_odd_functions&ei=ziYdVZW8L8Hx8gXB9IGQBQ&usg=AFQjCNGuhRXkFCf9XF71D1q4mXz9GdVdPQ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have, for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ (for you $a=10$)
$$\int_{-a}^a f(x) \text{d} x = \int_0^a f(x) \text{d} x + \int_{-a}^0 f(x) \text{d} x .$$

But thanks to a change of variable $u =-x$ 
$$ \int_{-a}^0 f(x) \text{d} x = \int_a^0 -f(-u)\text{d} u = \int_0^a f(-u) \text{d} u.$$

We finally obtain the result since $f$ is even which means that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Answer (score 3):

The integral $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx =2\int_{0}^a f(x)dx$ if the function is an even function and $ \sqrt{x^2+10}$ is an even function. Meaning $f(-x)=f(x)$